# Error While Opening Xbap (wpf Browser Applcation)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight, xbap

I am facing error while opening xbap in browser.
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
    Windows             : 6.3.9600.0 (Win32NT)
    Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.34014
    System.Deployment.dll       : 4.0.30319.34243 built by: FX452RTMGDR
    clr.dll             : 4.0.30319.34014 built by: FX45W81RTMGDR
    dfdll.dll           : 4.0.30319.34243 built by: FX452RTMGDR
    dfshim.dll          : 6.3.9600.16384 (winblue_rtm.130821-1623)

APPLICATION SUMMARY
    * Online only application.
    * Trust url parameter is set.   * Browser-hosted application.

ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * An exception occurred while determining platform requirements. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Unable to install or run the application. The application requires that assembly DPFPVerNET Version 1.6.1.0 be installed in the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) first. 
    * An exception occurred while downloading the application. Following failure messages were detected:
        + The DeterminePlatformRequirements method failed. The application cannot be committed.

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
    No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
    There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
    No phase information is available.

ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [9/28/2015 5:21:16 PM] System.Deployment.Application.DependentPlatformMissingException (Unknown subtype)
        - Unable to install or run the application. The application requires that assembly DPFPVerNET Version 1.6.1.0 be installed in the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) first. 
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.PlatformDetector.VerifyPlatformDependencies(AssemblyManifest appManifest, AssemblyManifest deployManifest, String tempDir)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentManager.DeterminePlatformRequirementsCore(Boolean blocking)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentManager.DeterminePlatformRequirements()
            at System.Deployment.Application.InPlaceHostingManager.AssertApplicationRequirements(Boolean grantApplicationTrust)
            at System.Deployment.Application.InPlaceHostingManager.AssertApplicationRequirements()
            at MS.Internal.AppModel.XappLauncherApp.AssertApplicationRequirementsAsync(Object unused)
    * [9/28/2015 5:21:16 PM] System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentException (Unknown subtype)
        - The DeterminePlatformRequirements method failed. The application cannot be committed.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentManager.WaitForAssertApplicationRequirements()
            at System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentManager.SynchronizeCore(Boolean blocking)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentMan[image]ager.SynchronizeAsyncWorker()

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
    No transaction information is available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By running run time environment of finger print device on client PC, you can over come this error!